# Show that we can only find $6$ biholomorphic mappings $\phi$.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I have a problem:

> Let $U$ be a connected open subset of a point $(0,0)$, and 
>   $$ M= \{(z,\ w) \in \Bbb C^2: \text{Im}w = |z w|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7} |z|^2 \text{Re}z^6 \}$$ 
>   Let $$\phi:\ U \to \Bbb C^2$$
>   such that 
>   $$\phi (0,0)=(0,0),\ \ \phi (M)\subset M \tag{*}$$
>
> Show that we can **only** find $6$ biholomorphic mappings $\phi$ such that $(*)$.

---

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about

$$\phi_k(z,w) = (ze^{2\pi  i k/6}, w)$$

for $k=0,\ldots 5$. Note that $w$, $|z|$ and $z^6$ are invariant under $\phi_k$, and hence so is $M$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks mrf. Can you add your proof? I mean How do you have the result as above?

Comment: @kimtahe6 Which part are you having problems with? It's almost self-evident that each $\phi_k$ is a biholomorphism, and that $\phi_k$ maps $M$ into $M$ follows from what I wrote.

Comment: Yes,since $w,\ |z|,\ z^6$ are invariant under $\phi_k$ then If we take $(z',w) = (ze^{2\pi  i k/6}, w) \in \phi(M)$, we have \begin{align*}|z' w|^2+|z'|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z'|^2\text{Re}\ z'^{6}&= |z{w}|^2+|z|^8+\dfrac{15}{7}|z|^2\text{Re}\ z^6\\ &=\text{Im}w \end{align*}. So $\phi(M) \subset M$. But I don't understand Why do you have $\phi_k$ is a biholomorphic?

Comment: @kimtahe6 You should have no trouble showing that $\phi_k$ is 1-1 and finding its inverse.

Comment: $\bullet$ We consider the map: \begin{align*}
 \phi_k: U&\to \Bbb C^2\\ 
 (z,w)&\mapsto \phi_k(z,w)= (f=ze^{2\pi  i k/6}, g=w),\ k=0,\ldots,5
\end{align*} We have each of the coodinate functions $f=ze^{2\pi  i k/6},\ g=w$ is holomorphic.                             $\bullet$ We show that $f$ is one - to - one and onto, and there's an inverse function $$\phi_{k}^{-1}:\Bbb C^2 \to U$$. In need, the function $\phi_k$ is injective if and only if for all $(z',w),\ (z'',w) \in U$, if $\phi_k(z',w) = \phi_k(z'',w)$, then $z' = z''$. Thus, $\phi_k$ is injective.

Comment: We have $\phi$ is surjective, because $$\forall (z',w) \in \Bbb C^2,\  \exists (z,w) \in U\ \text{such that}\  \phi_k(z,w)=(z',w)=(ze^{2\pi  i k/6},w)$$ But Can you post $\phi_{k}^{-1}=???$

Comment: Why we can **only** find $6$ biholomorphic mappings $\phi$???I mean Why we have no other mappings, except $6$ map $\phi_k(z,w) = (ze^{2\pi  i k/6}, w)$. On the other hand, my teacher said that If we want to show that $\phi$ is biholomorphic then we only need to calculate $\text{Jacobian} \phi_k$. But I don't know!!! huh huh!!!

Comment: I showed that "exists"since your hints. Can you show that we "**only**" have $6$ biholomorphic mappings $\phi$? mrf!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!